# Send value from Child window to Parent window (VB .net)

Tags: vb.net

I want to pass value from child window to parent window, I am passing value through session but obviously it will not update on parent window without any postback event. I need help how can I set value to textbox as soon as child popup close

Parent window code

```
 Protected Sub ImageButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton1.Click

        Session("lookup") = txtpartname.Text

        Dim javaScript As String = String.Format("winRef = window.open('lookup.aspx', 'popUpWindow', 'height=300,width=600,left=100,top=30,resizable=Yes,scrollbars=No,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=No'); winRef.focus();")

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(String), "OpenWindowScript", javaScript, True)

    End Sub

Protected Sub save_new_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles save_new.Click
        If (Session("partname") <> Nothing) Then
            txtpartname.Text = Session("partname")
        End If
        Dim ErrorCheck As Integer = Functions.CreateComplainEstimate(ReturnVal, LabelRecordType.Text, , TxtActualAmount.Text, txtTotalAmountDiscounted.Text, txtDiscount.Text, txtDiscountRate.Text, txtQuantity.Text, txtIRNumber.Text, txtpartIssuedDateTime.Text, txtpartReturnedDateTime.Text, txtcollectionfromfranchiseCWS.Text, txtPNADate.Text, txtIRNumberDateTime.Text, txtpaymenttofranchisecws.Text, CheckBoxValue(checkPartIssued), CheckBoxValue(checkPartNotArranged), CheckBoxValue(checkPartReceived), CheckBoxValue(checkPartReturned), CheckBoxValue(checkPNA), CheckBoxValue(checkWrongDebrief), CheckBoxValue(checkIncludeInEstimate), CheckBoxValue(checkIncludeInDebriefing), txtCompany.Text, txtDebreifingIn.Text, LabelBilingtype.Text, txtDiscountStatus.Text, txtConsumptionType.Text, txtpartname.Text)
        Session.Remove("partname")
        If ErrorCheck = 100 Then
            Session("incident") = ReturnVal
            Response.Redirect("Debriefing.aspx")
        Else
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Error Saving Inspection Fault!')", True)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Child window

```
  Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
        ' Response.Cookies("ID").Value = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(2).Text.ToString()
        Session("partname") = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(2).Text.ToString()
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "CloseWindowScript", "window.close();", True)

    End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: read: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13358/Refresh-a-GridView-control-on-the-parent-page-from

Comment: and : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29617/Partial-update-of-parent-page-via-AJAX-ASP-NET